# How to retieve token from login with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native application. And I have different API data where a user has access when he/she has logged in through a token string. At the moment a user can login and a token is being created. But now I want to retrieve that token string in another API call. So this is the API call for retrieving the Token string:

```
export const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const token = retrieveToken();
        if (token) {
            console.log(token);
            const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.65:8000/api/categories/main_groups/", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
                },
            });
            return await response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(token);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle API error
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

But after a user has logged in this error occurs:

```
Invariant Violation: TaskQueue: Error with task : Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN
```

But if I hardcoded the token string:

```
Authorization: "Token 6b015120cf9b976bd7f848a78007ca9e5ac5eb6f",
```

Then it works

code for retrieveToken:

```
export const retrieveToken = async () => {
    try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
        return token;
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle token retrieval error
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
};
```

The login looks like:

```
export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.65:8000/api/user/token/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password,
            }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        if (response.ok) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", data.token);
            //
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Error(data.token);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error("Login failed");
    }
};
```

How to pass the token string to the api call?

Comment: Are you using react native?

Comment: @kennarddh. yes, I have described that in the introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to await the token retrieval function.

```
export const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await retrieveToken();
      ...
```

Comment: @sprift Ah, thank you. Yes, that error is not show anymore.  But the backend call is not loading the data. Because if I do a  console.log("token", token); in the function retrieveToken it retuns 
 token null. So the big question remains. How to retrieve the token?

Comment: Ohhh, it was capital t: Token. Oke, thank you